# Example of a recursively enumerable set as a limit of recursive sets

Tags: recursion

I am reading Soare's book and I am trying to understand the following statement:
A function f has r.e. degree iff it is the limit of a recursive sequence ${f_{s}}_{s \in \mathbb{N}}$ and its modulus of convergence $m \leq_{T}f$.

However, I am trying to find an example to illustrate this theorem. Is it useful to identify the difference between recursive sets and r.e. set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure! The classic example of this is the characteristic function of the Halting Problem, which is recursively enumerable but not recursive.

This function, $f$, is defined as: $f(x)=1$ if $\varphi_x(x)$ halts, and $f(x)=0$ otherwise (where $\{\varphi_e: e\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is some standard enumeration of the partial computable functions).

Now $f$ is a limit of recursive functions in a natural way. Let $f_s(x)=1$ if $\varphi_x(x)$ halts *in at most $s$ stages*, and $f_s(x)=0$ otherwise. Then each $f_s$ is recursive, and their limit is $f$: $f(x)=1$ iff for all sufficiently large $s$, we have $f_s(x)=1$.  So the quoted result says that $f$ has r.e. degree (and indeed, $f$ itself **is** r.e.).

So this is an example of a function with r.e. degree being the limit of a sequence of recursive functions. *In general, though, such an $f$ need only have $\Delta^0_2$ degree!* (This is Shoenfield's Limit Lemma.) And there are lots of $\Delta^0_2$ degrees which are not r.e. degrees. In order to ensure that the limit of a sequence of recursive functions is of r.e. degree, we need to add a technical condition; this is the requirement that the modulus of convergence (that is, at what point $t=m(n)$ we see $f(n)$ "stabilize" - $f_s(n)=f(n)$ for all $s>t$) be "simple". And indeed, it's easy to see that in the example above, the modulus of convergence of $f$ is indeed $\le_Tf$.

Comment: Thanks Noah, it is a great example. My second part of the question is more related to the following: is this theorem helpful to show negative Answers? For example, I am trying to proof the following: if E is an equivalence relation r.e. which is not recursive, then for each n there are infinitely many classes whose size is different than n. Is there any way to use the limit lemma to show that something is not recursive?

Comment: @user350168 No, the limit lemma (and similar results) are used to provide an *upper* bound on complexity (if we know $f$ is the limit of an appropriate sequence of functions, then $f$ isn't "too complicated") or, in the other direction, to get "representations" of functions we know to be simple (e.g. going from a $\Delta^0_2$ function to a representation of it as a limit of functions). But recursive functions are *already* as simple as can be, and *trivially* have nice representations (e.g. $f$ is the limit of itself :P). So these results aren't really useful for providing *lower* bounds.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you very much, I learned a lot with this!